# How do I build with watch enabled using angular-cli?

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-cli

I don't want to use serve, I know it watches for changes, builds and serves.
I want to build upon changes.
According to "ng help", build takes parameter --watch

> ng build    Builds your app and places it into the output
>   path (dist/ by default).
>   --watch (Boolean) (Default: false)
>       aliases: -w   --watcher (String)

I tried both -w and --watcher but it just gives error.

```
>ng build -w

Path must be a string. Received null
```

Answer (score 70, accepted):

I don´t know if it´s a bug or just not documented, but it seems that you need to add a output path for watching with `ng build -o dist -w` while dist is your output path.

**Update:**

The command is now: `ng build -op dist -w`

**Update 2:**

The command is now: `ng build --output-path dist --watch`

Comment: right, it is a known issue: https://github.com/DavideViolante/Angular2-Full-Stack/issues/15
so this solves the problem: ng build -o dist -w

Comment: Thanks for the link. I updated my answer with your code snippet.

Comment: @StefanNegele Angular now has output path configuration in `angular.json` too, named as `outputPath`, under `options` variable.

Answer (score 38):

`ng build --watch` just worked for me

And if you are using `npm run build` update the `package.json` file as

`"scripts":{"build":"ng build --watch"}`

and run `npm run build` as usual

make sure that `outDir` param of your app is correctly set in your *angular-cli.json*

Comment: Just what I needed! Thanks

Comment: How to make sure that all the files are not removed from the outDir every time the build is run.

Answer (score 7):

The `ng build --watch` looks for the path: `dist` to watch the changes. But as per the new version of the Angular, the default output path will be `dist/<project-name>`.

So you need to mention the output directory through command line like

```
ng build --output-path dist --watch
```

**or**

you can change the default location in `angular.json... -> options -> outputPath: dist/<project-name>` to `dist` and simply run `ng build --watch`

Answer (score 0):

The command to build & watch AngularJs: `ng build --poll=2000 --watch`