# How to serve an angular elements app in watch mode?

Tags: angular, angular-elements

I have successfully created an Angular Elements application following [this awesome guide](https://winsmarts.com/getting-started-with-angular-elements-1bbdf2e748a6).

The "serve" process consists of:

1. Build the application and concat into a single js file `ng build --prod --output-hashing=none && cat dist/tamigo-calendar/{runtime,polyfills,scripts,main}.js > ./plainHTML/ship.js`
2. Now serve a HTML file, containing the custom element. In this case `lite-server`.

But every time I do a change to the custom element, and wan't to see it updated I need to re-run the build script. So my question is this, how can I build this in watch mode?

The relevant parts of my `package.json` looks like this:

```
"buildForShip": "ng build --prod --output-hashing=none && cat dist/tamigo-calendar/{runtime,polyfills,scripts,main}.js > ./plainHTML/ship.js",
"plainHTML": "lite-server"
"start": "npm run -s buildForShip && npm run -s plainHTML"
```

Comment: Please add your package.json's script object.

Comment: You can add `watch` option for `ng serve` and not for `ng build`

Comment: @inthevortex that's not true - you can run build in watch mode. Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43347849/3694288

Answer (score 2):

Following the article, you might have added a script named `plainHTML` in the `scripts` object of your `package.json` file. You can simply add `--watch` after it.

Something like this:

```
"plainHTML": "lite-server --watch"
```

This should run the server in watch mode and should look for file changes.

Also, since your file is going to be generated after building it, you can also use `--watch` in `ng build` for `buildForShip` script:

```
"buildForShip": "ng build --prod --watch --output-hashing=none && cat dist/tamigo-calendar/{runtime,polyfills,scripts,main}.js > ./plainHTML/ship.js",
```

Comment: but the `ship.js` file only updates when runnig the build command, so that won't work

Comment: Did you try running `ng build in --watch` mode?

Comment: yes - and that works. *But* I also need the files merged into one, like specified in the  build script (`&& cat dist/tamigo-calendar/{runtime,polyfills,scripts,main}.js > ./plainHTML/ship.js`) otherwise the lite-server won't pick it up

Comment: Hi, we have a similar problem with our micro app. Any updates? Did you find any solutions?